# Mapstruct - ignore field by name in whole project

Tags: java, mapping, mapstruct

I've got project, where I often map dto -> db model. Almost all my db models have some additional fields, like version, which are never mapped from dto.

Is there any possibility or elegant workaround to ignore target fields globally only by theirs names?

For now I have to use `@Mapping(target = "version", ignore = true)`. Cannot use `@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)`, because I'd like to get warns or errors when I accidentally omit any important property. I control default behavior with `'-Amapstruct.unmappedTargetPolicy=WARN'`, which I change for ERROR during developing new functions.

Some people may say that these are just warnings, but when there are many of them, it makes it harder to spot mistakes.

Mapstruct 1.3.1.Final, probably will move to 1.4.1.Final in nearest future. Searched through the [docs](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/), but couldn't find anything useful.

Thanks in advance for your answers :)

Comment: From what I understood you don't need the fields on the `dtos`s, right?

Comment: Yes, this field is specific for db model.
E.g:
Dto has fields name, desc and status, db model has id, name, desc, status and version.
I'd like to map only name, desc and status and ignore id and version in whole project, as they are managed by JPA.

Comment: `@Mapping(target = "version", ignore = true)` is when you have the field in both classes and don't want to map it. If a filed is **missing** from one side, it is automatically ignored. So, you don't have to do anything.

Comment: I cannot agree - just built project, got warning `warning: Unmapped target properties: "createdAt, modifiedAt, id,` from my mapper dto -> db.

Comment: Although, I noticed that when I don't provide setter for given field, the warning omits scecific field in warning message. It may partially solve the problem, but then there may be trouble with tests, where somewhere I set e.g. id manually.

I believe that automatic ignore is enabled for unmapped source property, for a while I'd have been thinging about enabling property `Amapstruct.unmappedSourcePolicy=WARN', but decided that it won't be necessary.

Comment: Sorry I'm not following, but in case of a test, why don't you set it manually? btw, `unmappedSourcePolicy` is `WARN`, you don;t have to set this too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Some people may say that these are just warnings, but when there are many of them, it makes it harder to spot mistakes.

First of all, I am glad you don't ignore warnings.

As of MapStruct 1.4 you can create an annotation that is composed of multiple mappings. Read more at the documentation of MapStruct 1.4.1. [3.2. Mapping Composition (experimental)](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#mapping-composition). This configuration can also be *shared* ([11.3. Shared configurations](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#shared-configurations)).

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
@Mapping(target = "version", ignore = true)
public @interface WithoutVersion { }
```

```
@Mapper
public interface DtoMapper {
   
   @WithoutVersion
   Dto entityToDto(Entity entity)
}
```

This becomes useful for example in the case of multiple fields to be ignored. The biggest advantage is that you take a control over mapping through the explicit use of the annotation and not a global configuration.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
@Mapping(target = "version", ignore = true)
@Mapping(target = "createdAt", ignore = true)
@Mapping(target = "modifiedAt", ignore = true)
@Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true)
public @interface WithoutMetadata { }
```

```
@Mapper
public interface DtoMapper {
   
   @WithoutMetadata 
   Dto entityToDto(Entity entity)
}
```

Comment: I like this solution, looks as elegant as I dreamt :)

Comment: On top of that you'll get an error if you are using a field that does not exist in the target / source mapping

Comment: Behind the scenes it is like you have defined the `@Mapping` on the method itself. Maybe you haven't made a mistake in your definitions :). Anyways, if you find anything that we can improve there, you know what to do